# Pasar datos entre formularios

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lenguaje: `C Sharp`

En el `MainForm` tengo un `datagridview` cuyo `datasource` es un `dataset` con un `datatable`.

Con un `botón` se abre el `form2` y en este se elige un número de fila.
Al aceptar, el `form2` debe cerrarse y el número elegido por el usuario va a usarse como índice de fila para eliminar en el `dataset` del `Main`

No sé cómo puedo pasar este dato. Encontré como pasar de un `form` a otro usando sus nombres de instancia al crearlos pero el `MainForm` se ejecuta solo, no sé que nombre tiene la instancia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clase Padre:

```
public partial class Padre : Form
{
    public Padre()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAbrirHijio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hijo hijo = new Hijo(); //Instancia del Hijo
        DialogResult res = hijo.ShowDialog(); //Llamamos nuestra ventana hija a manera de DialogResult
        if (res == DialogResult.OK) //Nos debe regresar un Dialogresult.OK
        {
            string IndiceSeleccionadoDesdeHijo = hijo.IndiceSeleccionado; //Y listo, nos traermos la informacion
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Hija:

```
public partial class Hijo : Form
{
    public string IndiceSeleccionado = ""; //Necesitaremos una clase global para obtener los datos desde la clase padre

    public Hijo() //Este es el contructor de la clase
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnAceptar.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; //Esto hara que al dar Click a nuestro boton, este regrese un DialogResult.OK y podamos cacharlo en la clase padre.

    }

    private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IndiceSeleccionado = txtIndice.Text; //Asignacion a variable global de la que el Padre extraera el dato

    }
}
```

Si necesitas ayuda me dices, pero en si esta es la logica que necesitas amigo.
Saludos!

Comment: Daré una pequeña explicación, si te fijas en el constructor de la clase hija |public Hijo()| esta la linea |btnAceptar.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;|, lo que le estoy diciendo al programa es que tras desencadenar el codigo de el evento |btnAceptar_Click| (es decir al darle clic a tu boton) va a regresar como resultado un |DialogResult.Ok|, es decir, finalizara la forma pero regresara ese valor.

Si te fijas, en la clase Padre llamo a la Ventana Hija con |Hijo hijo = new Hijo(); DialogResult res = hijo.ShowDialog();| Y despues atrapo el valor en el if siguiente en un String.

Comment: La explicación la puedes dar en la respuesta José, ahí se va a poder leer mejor.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Jose! Es lo que estaba buscando ;)

Comment: Esto debería tener más reputación, es algo que parece tan simple pero es muy útil.