# Pasar valor booleano entre formularios personalizados - Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una solución de tipo Windows Form que contiene dos formularios:

Formulario **frm_abrir_ventana**:

Campos:

- (1) Button "Abrir": *Abre el formulario llamado* **frm_nueva_ventana**.

Cuando este botón se oprime, se debe bloquear. Ejemplo: `Abrir.Enabled = false;`

---

Formulario **frm_nueva_ventana**:

Campos:

- (1) RadioButton: *Determina si el botón del formulario* **frm_abrir_ventana** *está habilitado.*
- (1) Button Finalizar: *Cierra el formulario actual* **(frm_nueva_ventana)** *y debe habilitar el botón del formulario* **frm_abrir_ventana**.

Estaba revisando esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/16293/78), pero no aplica a la situación que describo en mi pregunta.

El flujo del programa es el siguiente:

1. Oprimir el botón `Abrir` del formulario **frm_abrir_ventana**.
2. El evento `OnClick` del botón `Abrir`abre una instancia del formulario **frm_nueva_ventana** y bloquea el boton `Abrir`.
3. En el formulario **frm_nueva_ventana**, puede optar por seleccionar el `RadioButton`.
4. En el actual formulario **frm_nueva_ventana**, presione el botón `Finalizar`, enviando el `checked` (boolean) del `RadioButton` al primer formulario *es decir,* **frm_abrir_ventana**.
5. Establecer el valor del atributo `Enabled` al botón `Abrir` del formulario **frm_abrir_ventana**.

Para resumir, el problema que tengo en este momento es **enviar un valor boolean entre estos dos formularios**; cuando el segundo formulario termine su funcionalidad se debe cerrar y habilitar de nuevo el botón `Abrir`.

Este es mi código actual:

Código del formulario **frm_abrir_ventana**:

```
/// Propiedad pública del formulario "para habilitar el botón (Abrir)".
public bool EstadoBoton { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Abrir segundo formulario (frm_nueva_ventana).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void btnAbrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm_nueva_ventana frmNewVnt = new frm_nueva_ventana();
    frmNewVnt.Show();
    btnAbrir.Enabled = false;
}
```

Código **frm_nueva_ventana**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Cerrar actual formulario (frm_nueva_ventana) y enviar
/// el checked del RadioButton al botón del primer formulario.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void btnFinalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // frm_abrir_ventana aún está abierta y debe estarlo.
    // por lo que no sé tampoco cómo detectar este proceso.
    frm_abrir_ventana frmAbrVnt = new frm_abrir_ventana();
    frmAbrVnt.Show();
    frmAbrVtn.EstadoBoton = true;
}
```

**¿Cómo puedo establecer esta funcionalidad correctamente?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta puede ser una solución:

En el formulario **frm_abrir_ventana**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NavigateForms
{
    public partial class frm_abrir_ventana : Form
    {
        public frm_abrir_ventana()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAbrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Instancia de la nueva ventana
            frm_nueva_ventana frmNuevaVentana = new frm_nueva_ventana();
            //Mostramos el formulario
            frmNuevaVentana.Show();
            //Pasamos la instancia actual de este formulario por un metodo publico que
            //contiene el formulario frmNuevaVentana
            frmNuevaVentana.getFrm(this);
            //Inhabilitamos el botón
            btnAbrir.Enabled = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene el valor boleano del checkbox del formulario frmNuevaVentana
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="boleano"></param>
        public void getBoolean(bool boleano)
        {
            btnAbrir.Enabled = boleano;
        }
    }
}
```

En el formulario **frm_nueva_ventana**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NavigateForms
{
    public partial class frm_nueva_ventana : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Esta variable de tipo frm_abrir_ventana nos servira para almacenar la instancia
        /// de la "pagina principal"
        /// </summary>
        frm_abrir_ventana formInstancia = null;

        public frm_nueva_ventana()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnFinalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
           //Llamamos al metodo publico que se encuentra en el formulario frm_abrir_ventana y pasamos
           //el valor del checkedbox
           formInstancia.getBoolean(checkB.Checked);

            //cerramos este formulario
           this.Close();         
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Este metodo publico lo ocupamos en el formulario frm_abrir_ventana para poder pasar la instancia de la
        /// "pagina principal"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="form"></param>
        public void getFrm(frm_abrir_ventana form)
        {
            formInstancia = form;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Katz, bienvenido y gracias por aportar... Si bien está claro el código, pensando en futuros lectores de esta pregunta, quizás sería recomendable [edit] la respuesta agregando algo de texto explicando brevemente cómo es que soluciona lo que el autor está buscando.

Comment: Va!! Dame un momento y lo explico detallado.

Answer (score 2):

No tienes que crear una nueva instancia de `frm_abrir_ventana` cuando quieres volver a la ventana padre, debes usar la instancia existente

aqui
[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

explico sobre el tema

pero basicamente debes tener la instancia del form padre (en este caso `frm_abrir_ventana`) desde el form que estas abriendo `frm_nueva_ventana` para saber donde tienes que enviar el dato de una ventana a la otra

La ventana padre envia su instancia al otro form

```
public class frm_abrir_ventana
{
    public bool EstadoBoton { get; set; }


    private void btnAbrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm_nueva_ventana frmNewVnt = new frm_nueva_ventana(this);
        frmNewVnt.Show();
        btnAbrir.Enabled = false;
    }

}
```

La ventana hija recibe la instancia y la usa para enviar los datos

```
public class frm_nueva_ventana
{
    private frm_abrir_ventana frmAbrVnt;

    public frm_nueva_ventana()
    {
        InitialComponente();
    }

    public frm_nueva_ventana(frm_abrir_ventana frm) : this()
    {
        this.frmAbrVnt = frm;
    }


    private void btnFinalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmAbrVtn.EstadoBoton = true;
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

observa como en el constructor del form se pasa la instancia para no tener que crear una nueva, pudiendo de esta forma pasar el valor de un lado al otro

Comment: Leandro, desafortunadamente no pude lograr que funcionara la lógica que has explicado en detalle en tu respuesta, pero he votado a favor, ya que es una respuesta completa y que puede ayudar a otros. +1 y gracias nuevamente por compartir tus conocimientos.

Comment: porque no lograste que funcionara? quizas si lo explicas podriamos analizar que esta faltando. La otra respuesta que marcas es casi igua a la que propongo solo que la instancia en lugar de pasarla en el constructor esta haciendo uso de un metodo que expone el form hijo

Comment: Con el código que has proporcionado, al probarlo, cuando se cierra el formulario actual no habilita nuevamente el botón `Abrir` del formulario principal. Es lo que pude ver y _como me están apresurando con este desarrollo_ me es difícil dedicarle mas tiempo para "pulir" detalles. Te agradezco nuevamente.