# ¿Cómo cerrar un form en C# y que se habra otro?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, botón

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que un button me cierre un form y abra otro?

```
private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    infol = cq.labelinfo();
    mover mv = new mover();
    mv.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

Este código abre el form `mover` pero no me cierra el otro.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cierre el primer form, pero abra el segundo?

Comment: ¿Intentaste ejecutar `this.Close()` antes que `mv.ShowDialog()`?

Comment: me cierra el form1 sin abrir el de mover!!

Comment: @use2105 revisa esta [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21024/78)

Comment: 'mv.ShowDialog()' <--- es para abrir un ´modal´, los formularios modal siempre dependen del padre.  
Otro punto importante es que si el formulario que quieres cerrar es el Principal obviamente va cerrar toda la aplicación.

Answer (score 9):

Primeramente, a menos que tengas una buena razón para usar [`Form.ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx), te sugiero de usar simplemente [`Form.Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.show(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mover mv = new mover();
    mv.Show();

    this.Close();
}
```

Ahora bien, el código tal cual debería funcionar correctamente. El problema es que en este caso `this.Close()` está cerrando el form principal. Por defecto, cuando cierras el form principal en un proyecto WinForms, esto pone fin al programa entero.

Si no deseas que el programa termine al cerrar el form principal, puedes hacer una pequeña modificación en el `Main()` de tu proyecto. Pongámosle que tu form principal se llama `MainForm`, entonces, verás que tu `Main()` se va a parecer a algo como esto:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainForm()); // hay que modificar aquí
}
```

Si cambias este código para ejecutar [`Application.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx) sin pasarle una instancia de `MainForm`, esto hace que el programa no termine cuando se cierre el form principal, y esto va a corregir tu problema si lo vuelves a intentar:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MainForm main = new MainForm();
    main.Show();
    Application.Run(); // quítale el parámetro aquí
}
```

Ahora bien, aunque con este cambio sencillo técnicamente tu pregunta queda resuelta, el cambio también tiene por efecto de que cuando cierres todas las ventanas abiertas, aunque parezca que el programa está terminado, verás que en realidad sigue corriendo (verás que el process todavía corre en el Task Manager).  Como el cerrar el form principal ya no acaba con el programa, recae en ti de ejecutar manualmente [`Application.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx) cuando deseas poner fin al programa.

De forma alternativa, si quieres que el programa se acabe automáticamente cuando ya no queda ninguna ventana abierta, puedes hacer un ajuste más al `Main()` para manejar esta situación de forma automática (esta idea la saqué de esta excelente respuesta en SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/4955425):

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MainForm main = new MainForm();
    main.FormClosed += MainForm_Closed; // agrega esto aquí
    main.Show();
    Application.Run();
}

private static void MainForm_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Form)sender).FormClosed -= MainForm_Closed;

    if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0)
    {
        Application.ExitThread();
    }
    else
    {
        Application.OpenForms[0].FormClosed += MainForm_Closed;
    }
}
```

Comment: me ayudo bastante Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Así como lo pones no es posible porque estás llamando a una ventana hija (ShowDialog). Intenta llamarla sólo con Show() `mv.Show();`

Puedes leer la siguiente liga para que te aclares un poco. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: si lo pongo asi solo cierra el programa, no abre nada

Comment: El form que estás intentando cerrar es el principal?

Comment: si, es el form principal

Comment: Como puedo hacer para saber si el form mover se abrio?? Pienso que si hago un if donde diga que si form mover abrio cierre form principal pero no se como hacerlo...

Comment: Tal como explicó @VEga en la otra respuesta, si cierras el form principal, cierras todas las ventanas hijas.

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberias abrir el nuevo formulario en un nuevo hilo, porque al crearlo sobre el mismo hilo, al cerrar el formulario principal, matas todos sus hijos, ademas si cierras el formulario principal es probable que pierdas algunos valores de tu contexto.
Para este caso lo que yo te recomiendo es utilizar formularios MDI, si no requieres que se vea el formulario principal puedes ponerle un valor setVisble en false y así solo mostrar los Formularios hijos.
[MSDN Cómo: Crear formularios MDI secundarios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/7aw8zc76(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm2 fm= new frm2();
    this.Hide();
    fm.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo siempre explicar un poco su respuesta aun cuando esta sea un tanto obvio

Answer (score 0):

Sigue los pasos de la primera respuesta y cuando quieras cerrar la aplicación, simplemente creas el evento FormClosing en el formulario desde el cuál quieres cerrar la aplicación. Ejemplo:
Si quieres que la aplicación termine cuando cierras el Form secundario, tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
   private void NombreFormSecundario_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Y listo, cuando cierres ese form (le des clic a la X roja del form), la aplicación finalizará completamente.