# Presionar un boton desde otro Form en C#

Tags: c#

Como puedo hacer para que al presionar un boton de un form1 se  presione otro boton de otro form2 y el form2 se cierre??

```
// cambio el boton a public
public void btnoperator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

// en el otro form preosiono el boton del form1 y cierro el form2
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1.btnoperator.PerformClick();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Lo que pasa es que el la funccion `f1.btnoperator.PerformClick();` no funciona, no le da click al boton del otro form.

Comment: quieres que ambos botones hagan el mismo codigo? creas una funcion que la llames desde cada uno, desde las propiedades de los botones cambias el evento para que llamen a la misma

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta. Que es lo que está mal en el código que nos pones? Te da algún error o no hace lo que quieres? Edita tu pregunta y explica bien el problema

Comment: ya la edite, gracias.

Comment: El Form2 se abre desde el Form1? Si es así, sería sencillo cerrarlo directamente desde el Form1

Comment: si, si lo abro desde el form1

Comment: Si tu código solo lo cierra, puedes coger la variable en la que está guardada el Form2 y hacer: `frm2.Close()`

Comment: como puedo saber si un boton fue presionado ??

Comment: @use2105, por favor revisa [mi pregunta y la respuesta aceptada](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21023/78), creo que esto es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Has tu metodo click para button en Form2 publico y lo llamas desde el metodo click del Form1, desde esta forma:

```
Class Form1
{
    public void Form1()
    { }

    private void button_Click(sender, e)
    {
        var frm = new Form2();

        frm.Show();
        frm.button_Click(this, null);
        frm.Close();
    }
}

Class Form2
{
    public void Form2()
    { }

    public void button_Click(sender, e)
    {
        ///...Tu codigo...///
    }
}
```

O desde el diseñador de Form1 podrías instanciar Form2 y suscribirte al evento con el mismo método que tienes en Form2, de esa forma practica el efecto que tendrá el click en Form2 sera el mismo que el click en Form1, hace lo mismo que el código que te puse arriba pero un poco mas practico.