# ¿Pasar datos de un objeto creado en un form secundario a otro formprincipal?

Tags: c#, objeto

Necesito realizar un programa en C# que tenga un MainForm, con una lista de datos de clientes  y un boton de agregar datos de clientes. A su vez si hago click en este boton, me deberia abrir otro form donde poder ingresar los datos de clientes, clickear aceptar y luego cerrarse la ventana para volver al MainForm donde en la lista se actualizaria con el nombre agregado.

Mi problema reside en que hago el MainForm, hago el otro form que se abre al clickear el boton, ingreso el nombre y demas datos, donde creo un nuevo objeto cliente y le almaceno lo ingreso pero al cerrar esta segunda ventana pierdo el objeto y no se como pasarlo al MainForm y agregarlo a la lista. Desde el segundo Form no me reconoce el objeto lista del MainForm como para agregarlo ahi mismo.

Comment: Te puede servir esta pregunta, es exactamente lo mismo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21023/pasar-valor-booleano-entre-formularios-personalizados-windows-form/21024#21024

Comment: Deberías colocar lo que haz intentado.

Answer (score 1):

hay muchas maneras para hacer esto, pero lo primero que necesitas hacer es que una instancia sea llamable desde la otra. o acceder a variables globales en el program.cs

un metodo sencillo y buena practica es que tu forma principal sea un objeto global publico en tu program cs, de esta manera podrás acceder a el desde cualquier parte con program.MainForm

pero como en c# la forma principal es un objeto anónimo, entonces no puede referenciarse directamente, para arreglar esto tenemos que modificar la clase program.cs

```
 public form Mainform 

 Mainform = new form(); 
 Application.Run(Mainform);
```

otro método menos invasivo es utilizar la propiedad parent para poder acceder a las propiedades de la forma invocada desde la forma principal o la forma que lo invoca:

dentro del mainform en la declaración de la nueva forma

```
 form formasecundaria = new form();
 formasecundaria.Parent = (this);
```

dentro de la formasecundaria;

```
this.Parent.propiedad = this.propiedad;
```

la mejor practica es determinar que tan volátiles y en cuantas partes estas propiedades deben ser utilizadas.

Variables/propiedades globales son propiedades que no deberían ser modificadas cada vez que queremos asignar nuevos valores.

y tener que hacer a la forma principal parent siempre es codigo algo molesto

considero que la mejor practica es que la forma principal sea un objeto global, de esta manera se pueden acceder a todas las demás propiedades dentro de tu codigo.