# Pasar un valor de un Formulario a otro c#

Tags: c#, seguridad

Estoy trabajando con lenguaje c# y sql server para un sistema de un centro de estudios, tengo que mandar 3 variables obtenidas de un datatable, donde selecciono Acceso, Nombre y Apellidos. Esas variables las tengo que, mandar al segundo formulario, pero al pasarlas no las lee en él segundo formulario. Esto lo necesito, ya que es para  los privilegios del usuario.

***Método logear***

```
public void logear(string usuario,string contraseña)
    {
        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Acceso,[Primer Nombre],Apellidos from Administradores where Usuario = @usuario and contraseña = @contraseña", Con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contraseña", contraseña);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            if(dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                frmprincipal frm = new frmprincipal();

                
                frm.acceso = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                frm.Nombre = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                frm.Apellidos =dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();

                MessageBox.Show("Acceso dt " + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Nombre  dt" + dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Apellidos dt " + dt.Rows[0][2].ToString());

                MessageBox.Show("acceso frm" + frm.acceso);
                MessageBox.Show("Nombre frm" + frm.Nombre);
                MessageBox.Show("Apellidos frm" + frm.Apellidos);

                FrmSlach splach = new FrmSlach();
                splach.Show();
                this.Hide();

                MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido al Sistema " + frm.Nombre + "  " + frm.Apellidos);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecta");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Luego al aceptar en el formulario login mando a llamar a este método

***Formulario principal***

Creo 3 variables globales

```
  public string acceso = " ";
  public string Nombre = " ";
  public string Apellidos = " ";
```

***Método gestión usuarios***

```
private void GestionUsuarios()
        {
            if (acceso == "ADMINISTRADOR")
            {
                this.administracionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled=true;
                this.matriculasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.inventariosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.contabilidadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.consultasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.salirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.regresarLoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.backupToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.btnadministracion.Enabled = true;
                this.btncentro.Enabled = true;
                this.btnestudiante.Enabled = true;
                this.btninformacion.Enabled = true;
                this.btnsalir.Enabled = true;

            }else if( acceso == "RECEPCION")
            {
                this.administracionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.matriculasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.inventariosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.contabilidadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.consultasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.salirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.regresarLoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.backupToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.btnadministracion.Enabled = false;
                this.btncentro.Enabled = false;
                this.btnestudiante.Enabled = false;
                this.btninformacion.Enabled = true;
                this.btnsalir.Enabled = true;

            }else if (acceso == "COORDINACION ACADEMICA")
            {
                this.administracionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.matriculasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.inventariosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.contabilidadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.consultasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.salirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.regresarLoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.backupToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.btnadministracion.Enabled = false;
                this.btncentro.Enabled = false;
                this.btnestudiante.Enabled = true;
                this.btninformacion.Enabled = true;
                this.btnsalir.Enabled = true;

            }else if(acceso == "USUARIO")
            {
                this.administracionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.matriculasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.inventariosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.contabilidadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.consultasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.salirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.regresarLoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.backupToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.btnadministracion.Enabled = false;
                this.btncentro.Enabled = false;
                this.btnestudiante.Enabled = true;
                this.btninformacion.Enabled = true;
                this.btnsalir.Enabled = true;
            }else
            {
                /*this.administracionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.matriculasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.inventariosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.contabilidadToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.consultasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.salirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.regresarLoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                this.backupToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                this.btnadministracion.Enabled = false;
                this.btncentro.Enabled = false;
                this.btnestudiante.Enabled = false;
                this.btninformacion.Enabled = false;
                this.btnsalir.Enabled = true;*/

                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
```

Luego solo mando a llamar a la función gestionUsuarios() en el load del formulario principal.

Comment: Considere ver esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21023/78) y las respuestas para que pueda adaptar su código.

Answer (score 1):

Creo entender tu problema, sin embargo deberías considerar reformular tu pregunta.

Intenta declarar las 3 variables privadas en el formulario FrmSlach. Luego, al momento de obtener las variables del datatable hacer esto:

```
frm.acceso = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
frm.Nombre = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
frm.Apellidos =dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();

splach.acceso = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
splach.Apellidos =dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
splach.Nombre = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```