# Compartir variables entre windows forms

Tags: c#

Como puedo compartir variables entre windows forms y windows controls?

Tengo en el control lo siguiente:

```
if (oTcConfig.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
////Asignamos los valores introducidos por el usuario a las variables internas
ConfData.TcCnf.NormType = (byte)(oTcConfig.comboBoxNormType.SelectedIndex + 1);
}
```

Después en otra forma hago lo siguiente:

```
public void grabarEnToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
 label1.Text = ConfData.TcCnf.NormType.ToString();
}
```

Me introduce el valor de la inicialización y no el valor real del combo box. Es como si la variable no se hubiera actualizado.

Comment: en el Formulario1 create una variable privada para guardar el valor que te interesa recuperar en el Formulario2, tambien create un metodo publico que devuelva ese valor. Luego desde el Formulario2 llamas al metodo publico que has creado y ya tienes ese valor para poder trabajar con el.

Comment: Puedes encontrar la respuesta en esta discusión: [Click Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16293/pasar-datos-entre-formularios)

Comment: De acuerdo gracias.