# Evitar ShowDialog de ingreso de parametros

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crystal-reports

estoy tratando de pasar valores de parámetros, a mi reporte, pero a la hora de pasarle el parámetro me sale la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago click en "Imprimir ticket", le paso el valor del parámetro a mi visor así:

```
private void btnImprimirTicket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (dtgvPedidos.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
        idPed = Convert.ToInt32(dtgvPedidos.CurrentRow.Cells["Número_Pedido"].Value.ToString());

        Formularios.frmVisorDetallePedido visor = new frmVisorDetallePedido(idPed);
        this.Hide();
        visor.Show();
      }
      else {
        MessageBox.Show("No hay pedidos actualmente en esta mesa, por favor cree uno nuevo o dirijase a otra mesa.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
}
```

Y en mi visor tengo el siguiente código:

```
public frmVisorDetallePedido(int idPed)
{
      InitializeComponent();

      this.idPed = idPed;
}

int idPed;

private void MostrarInforme()
{
      Reportes.rptDetallePedido d = new Reportes.rptDetallePedido();
      d.SetParameterValue("IdPed", idPed);
      crVisor.ReportSource = d;
      d.Refresh();
}

private void crVisor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      MostrarInforme();
}
```

Comment: deberias de ediatr tu pregunta, eso es "pasar datos entre formularios" y hay varias preguntas resueltas en el foro.

Comment: revisa este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16293/pasar-datos-entre-formularios

Comment: Hola Manny, no es pasar datos entre formularios porque eso si me funciona, por algo no puse "Como pasar datos entre formularios", lo que necesito es saber porque me sale el Dialog para pasar parametros, si yo ya le estoy seteando un valor.

Comment: ya veo, no puedo ver tu imagen, estoy desde una red privada, dale un ojo a este link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/crystal-report-with-parameter-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/