# Pasar todas las filas y columnas de un listview2 formularioa a otro listview1 en un formulario b

Tags: c#, listview

1. Tengo dos formularios padre e hijo.
2. En cada formulario hay un listview.
3. Quiero pasar datos del form hijo listview a formpadre listview.
4. Adjunto imagen con codigo, donde solo me pasa la primera columna.
5. Codigo usado. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiGmL.jpg![introducir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiGmL.jpg!%5Bintroducir) la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWUvD.jpg)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca tu código y no coloques imágenes, así podemos ayudarte mejor

Comment: :( solo capture en imagen :(

Comment: Puedo enviarme el archivo para abrirlo en visual

Comment: Quizás sea esto lo que buscas https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16294/169744